# How do I use TFS Build 2008 and my Web Deployment Project?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, tfs, web-deployment-project

I wish to create a TFS Build for my solution. Is there anyway I can just make the TFS Build, build my WDP only .. and not everything in the solution, etc?

Secondly, is there a special keyword I can use to tell my WDP that when it's a TFSBuild, it sets the ouput/drop directory to 'XXX' instead of the current hardocded output directory of 'zzzzzz'?

thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

TeamBuild will build everything in the solution.  If you want less things built, then give it a solution with less projects in it.  But if you are using project references; you need at least all the projects that have those.  The solution file under source control should be the one you want TeamBuild to use.  You can have as many as you want for your own personal use, but those don't need to be source controlled.

I wouldn't use a Web Deployment Project if you are using TeamBuild.  TeamBuild replaces the deployment project.  You insert a post build task into the msbuild script to copy the files to your test environment.

EDIT:

```
<Target Name="AfterDropBuild">
    <!-- Copy output assemblies -->
    <Message Text="SiteFilesToPublish location is $(DropLocation)\$(BuildNumber)" Importance="Low" />

    <CreateItem Include="$(DropLocation)\$(BuildNumber)\Default\_PublishedWebsites\IC.Web\**\*.*" Exclude="*.pdb" >
        <Output ItemName="SiteFiles" TaskParameter="Include" />
    </CreateItem>

    <Copy
      SourceFiles="@(SiteFiles)"
      DestinationFiles="@(SiteFiles ->'\\genweb.lab.dev\Test Lab\Independence Compliance\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)')"
      ContinueOnError="true" />
</Target>
```

Comment: Can you please post some examples about a "post build task into the msbuild script", please?

Comment: <AfterDropBuild> <Exec Command='xcopy /E <from> <to>' /> </AfterDropBuild>

Comment: I added an example of what I use on one of my projects.